# use data from two or more columns when using .map to apply a function

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I want to calculate the difference between two dates in format YYYY-MM-DD. When I write df["diff"] = df["date1"] - df["date2"] I get a value like 75 days which I can't sort.

How can I write it such that I map to function calc_diff(date1,date2) where

```
def calc_diff(date1,date2):
x = float(date2-date1)
return x
```

I.e. I df["diff"] = df["date1"],df["date2"].map(calc_diff)

when I write the following, I get:

```
df["until_payable"] = map(calc_diff, df["ex_div_date"], "date_payable")

def calc_diff(d1,d2):
    y = pd.to_datetime(d1)
    x = pd.to_datetime(d2)
    return x-y
```

Error:

```
<ipython-input-167-b151c936730f> in calc_diff(d1, d2)
     39     y = pd.to_datetime(d1)
     40     x = pd.to_datetime(d2)
---> 41     return x-y
     42 
     43 #convert the data in columns to data types

pandas/tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib._Timestamp.__sub__ (pandas/tslib.c:17620)()

TypeError: descriptor '__sub__' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly than the solution to your problem is:

```
res = map(calc_diff, date1, date2)
```

Please note that `date1` and `date2` should be the same length

Comment: Zachi Shtain - any idea what is causing the error - requires a datetime, but received a string?

Comment: @yoshiserry - the second argument you send is a `string` and not a `datetime` object